# remove noise that doesn't last for a specific time range in a time series

Tags: r, function, noise

I have a time series of event frequencies, like below:

```
df <- data.frame("time" = c(1:20), 
    "frq" = c(0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 0, 1 ))
```

(Assume `time` is from 1 to 20 seconds just to explain things easier)

I'm trying to write a function that will filter out noise from my signal. 
I consider the frequencies to be "noise" if the frequencies are not larger than a background value for a specific time.

For instance, let's say I want to only keep frequencies that are larger than `1` for longer than 3 seconds.  `df[3:4,2]` are "noise" because they are larger than 1 for only 2 seconds, while `df[7:10,2]` are not "noise" because they are larger than 1 and last for 4 seconds. Eventually I'd like to keep all values that are not noise and change all the noise values into `0`. So I'm trying to come up with a filter that will return:

```
return_df <- data.frame("time" = c(1:20), 
   "frq" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 0)`
```

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R, we can use `rle`

```
df$frq[!with(rle(df$frq > 1), rep(values & lengths >= 3, lengths))] <- 0
df

#   time frq
#1     1   0
#2     2   0
#3     3   0
#4     4   0
#5     5   0
#6     6   0
#7     7   2
#8     8   2
#9     9   4
#10   10   3
#11   11   0
#12   12   0
#13   13   0
#14   14   0
#15   15   0
#16   16   2
#17   17   4
#18   18   2
#19   19   0
#20   20   0
```